# move_uploaded_file error when display images

Tags: codeigniter

I'm trying to implement an image uploader, but when I want to display the images I get this error. Also, as I can see it doesn't upload it in the specified folder. What I am doing wrong?

```
move_uploaded_file(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Codeigniter/uploads/41d3f16b60a5e8.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Message: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move \'/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/phpAFbOft\' to \'/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Codeigniter/uploads/41d3f16b60a5e8.jpg\'

file_get_contents(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Codeigniter/uploads/41d3f16b60a5e8.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

can you describe what are you trying to do ?

move_upload_file accepts two parameter . and you are just passing it the file path .

have a look at this

http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: I've edited the question with the controller's code.

Comment: You could re-edit your first answer rather than creating two answers

Answer (score 0):

lets make this simple

```
if(isset($_FILES['myfile']['name']))
{ 
    $file = $_FILES['myfile']['name'];
    $location  = 'img/upload/';
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'],$location.$file))
    {
        $ImagePath = $location.$file;
        $imagedata = file_get_contents($ImagePath);
        $ret       = base64_encode($imagedata);
    }
}
```

hope this will work for you

Comment: Can you be more specific, please? Where should I use this one?